# getting message “Make sure you have at least one recent message created.” in ZAPIER

Tags: zapier

I am working on zapier, where I have created a zap with my app(Test Message) as trigger , now when I test my app as trigger while making a zap it shows "Make sure you have at least one recent Test Message created." and therefore i have to skip the test and make an action without testing my trigger.

Comment: What's your question? In order to test a trigger you have to force the trigger source to send new data as a test so Zapier can see the fields that are passed along.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your trigger isn't working or you didn't test it per the instructions.  You need to cause your external system to perform the action that would have caused your Zap to trigger.  For example, if your trigger `GitHub > New Repository`, you have to actually go make a new repository on GitHub, and then return to Zapier to let it test (you can delete that new repository after you're done).  If you can't, it's going to be difficult or possibly impossible to move forward.

This question seems to be a duplicate of [getting message "Make sure you have at least one recent message created." in ZAPIER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371420/getting-message-make-sure-you-have-at-least-one-recent-message-created-in-zap).